# IDs from a Select statement with GROUP BY and HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to select (or delete) all the IDs that are included in the following SQL...

```
SELECT ID 
FROM AHsTransactions
GROUP BY TypeID, AH1ID, AH2ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The question is how to get the ID from the rows that are within this grouping?

A simple dataset would be:
    `INSERT INTO AHsTransactions(TypeID, AH1ID, AH2ID) VALUES (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4)`

I've got it working using multiple SQL statements, but isn't this possible in one SQL statement??

1) `SELECT TypeID, AH1ID, AH2ID FROM AHsTransactions
            GROUP BY TypeID, AH1ID, AH2ID
            HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1`

Then I go through the returned rows and delete (or select ID )...

2) `DELETE FROM AHsTransactions WHERE 
    TypeID=$row[$i]['TypeID'] AND
    AH1ID=$row[$i]['AH1ID'] AND
    AH2ID=$row[$i]['AH2ID']`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: MSSQL but porting to MySQL :/

Answer (score 1):

Add `Id` in the `GROUP BY` clause, it is compulsory to add every column in group by which is present in select statement:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM AHsTransactions
GROUP BY ID, TypeID, AH1ID, AH2ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: But if i group by ID, then there is never a COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: @Mark share some dummy data and what is expected result

Comment: `INSERT INTO AHsTransactions(TypeID, AH1ID, AH2ID)
 VALUES (1, 2, 3),
  (1, 2, 3),
  (1, 2, 4)`


I would want to return the ID of only the last column.

Answer (score 0):

You must also group by `id`.  That's what the error message is telling you. Add it to your `group by` list. In general, if it's in your select list, you must also group by it.

Comment: But if i group by ID, then there is never a COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: then don't group by ID.  Then your query doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why would ID be in the select list if you don't want a count of things *by ID*? It's really unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ Chris - exactly ;)  but how to select the IDs that make up that grouping?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear.   I've got it working using multiple SQL statements. Maybe there is a way to combine the two?

`SELECT TypeID, AH1ID, AH2ID FROM AHsTransactions
   GROUP BY TypeID, AH1ID, AH2ID
   HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1'

Then I go through the returned rows and delete...

`DELETE FROM AHsTransactions WHERE 
 TypeID=$row[$i]['TypeID'] AND
 AH1ID=$row[$i]['AH1ID'] AND
 AH2ID=$row[$i]['AH2ID']`